# Is there a way to allow mongoose field to be undefined depending on the situation?

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an app that is making an ajax call to a server in order to save a user's information inside of a DB with mongoose. The ajax call looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url:"http://localhost:3000/updateuser",
                data: {
                    _id        : userID,
                    userEvents : events,
                    userGroups : groups,
                    latitude   : position.coords.latitude, 
                    longitude  : position.coords.longitude
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);

                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('there was an error');
                }
            });
```

The remote server to save the user's information looks like this:

```
var user   = {_id        : req.query._id};
var update = { events    : req.query.userEvents,
               groups    : req.query.userGroups,
               latitude  : req.query.latitude,
               longitude : req.query.longitude,
               timestamp : thisTime};

locationModel.update(user,update,{multi:true},function(err,numAffected){
    console.log(numAffected);
    console.log(err);
```

The problem that I'm running into is that sometimes userEvents or userGroups is sent as an empty field. It all depends on the user, and I can't guarantee that the field will be filled. If the field is empty, I get the following error from mongoose:

```
 undefined
 { message: 'Cast to string failed for value "undefined" at path "events"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'string',
  value: undefined,
  path: 'events' }
```

Does anybody know if there is a workaround for this issue? Please let me know if I am not clear on anything in the question. Thanks.

Comment: `events : req.query.userEvents || ""`?

Comment: You can only use @WiredPrairie solution if you are happy for the events to get overwritten when running an update. You should really build your update object to fit the data being passed in from the front end.

Comment: That will definitely do the trick. Having the events overwritten if they don't exist actually follows the logic of my application. @WiredPrairie if you want to submit that as an answer I'll give you the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind that the data will be overwritten in the document, you can just use the `||` operator and return an empty string (or any other value) anytime the left-hand-side of the operator evaluates to a "falsey" value:

```
events : req.query.userEvents || ""
```